# Отключиь рекламу в Skype android

Tags: android, skype

Добрый день. Как можно убрать рекламу в мобильном (android) скайпе. Думаю нужно что то, где то изменить. Подскажите знающие люди. Спасибо.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что н связан с программированием

Comment: Выключите интернет у телефона и скайп не будет показывать рекламу :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Собственно разобрался. Как я и ожидал всё в хостах. Всё дело в файле system/etc/hosts. Наши забугорные друзья из xda-developers сделали host файл со всеми рекламодателями скайпа. Собственно нужно заменить хост файл. качаем либо с их сайта либо `https://yadi.sk/d/fkFSzfKQhp6bd`. Для замены лучше использовать Root Browser. После перезаписи не забываем остановить и запустить skype.